# Merge several SQLite databases on memory database with TCL

Tags: database, sqlite, tcl, in-memory-database

I need to add into the memory database the content of several databases that are stored on files.
These databases are very big and with insert all, I need much time.
There is some method to do this merge efficient? I know that with one file, we can use the backup method, maybe there is someone method to do the merge.

Comment: Have you tried `ATTACH DATABASE` and then just `INSERT SELECT`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest method is probably to attach the other databases to the in-memory one and then do suitable table-to-table copies:

```sh
db eval {
    ATTACH DATABASE 'other.sqlite3' AS other;
}

# Do this for every database and every table you are interested in
# Or write your queries to keep some data in the other databases; your call
db eval {
    INSERT INTO main.fooTable SELECT * FROM other.fooTable;
}
```

You can also do reworking of the data while doing that bulk transfer. It should be fairly quick, as you say you're writing to an in-memory database and that doesn't need major integrity guarantees.

Comment: You can do the filename in the `ATTACH DATABASE` as a parameter, but the database name (“`other`”) can't be done like that.